# Remove child nodes in xml file : python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

In Python, how do I remove children nodes using element tree?

I wanna remove all children nodes of specific node.

Original xml file:

```
<node class = "X" ...>
   <node class = "y" ...>
   <node class = "A" ...>
      <node class = "z" ...>
      <node class = "q" ...>
   <node class = "y" ...>
</node>
```

and expecting xml file as below:

```
<node class = "X" ...>
   <node class = "y" ...>
   <node class = "A" ...>
   <node class = "y" ...>
</node>
```

I need to remove all children nodes of specific Node which have attrib class = "A"

Comment: Hint: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.remove

Comment: Or you can use [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).